# Irreducible action of a group on the tangent space of a manifold

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, group-actions

Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold. Let $G$ be a finite group of smooth maps from $M$ to $M$. Assume that the action of $G$ induced on the tangent space of $M$ at $p\in M$ is nontrivial and irreducible.

What is the definition and interpretation of the action of $G$ being nontrivial and irreducible in this context? Could you provide an introductory reference (textbook) where I can learn about these concepts?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrreducibleRepresentation.html ?

Comment: Possibly, but this definition does not occur in the context of tangent spaces of manifolds and does not mention the property of action. If the manifold is unimportant for the definition (i.e. you only need to perform the action on a linear space), then this could be it.